# Why is the molecular partition function only broken down into translational, rotational, vibrational, and electronic states, ignoring configurations?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry, partition-function

Per Atkins and others, energy is the sum of contributions from the translational, rotational, vibrational, and electronic modes of motion. Since the formula for the partition function is $Q=\sum_i e^{\beta E_i}$, Q is distributed into these 4 modes.

However, those 4 modes miss many of the $i$ configurations. For example, cyclohexane has boat and chair configurations, as well as many in-between. If I were to use the formulas for the 4 components of the partition function found in Atkins and other textbook, the partition function couldn't possibly include these different configurations.

Also, per my understanding of molecular mechanics, energy (of an ideal gas, using the same assumption used in the molecular partition function) is typically broken down into bonds (vibrations), angles, and dihedrals, as well as other contributions.

So does the molecular partition function that Atkins derives only work for molecules small enough to only contain bonds, but no angle or dihedral terms? I can't see it working for anything but a diatomic species then, which I know isn't right...

Answer (score 1):

The molecule has only 3*N (number of atoms) positional degrees of freedom, since every atom can move in 3 dimensions. Three of of the 3N are translations of the whole molecule, 3 are rotational and 3N-6 are vibrational (symmetry will even break these into invariant subspaces) Thus the partition function includes all relevant microstates in this definition.

Comment: I suppose that one could get cyclohexane from the chair to the boat configuration using only vibrations, if vibrations are defined as being everything except translations and rotations (which they are: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_vibration).

However, if one were to use a QM software like Gaussian to calculate the vibrational partition function (http://www.gaussian.com/g_whitepap/thermo.htm) for cyclohexane in the chair configuration, it wouldn't have deviated enough from its initial configuration to include the boat configurations, correct?